# Cutting an object with a plane using the Intersect Boolean opposite side

Tags: modifiers

I am using blender 3.4 which should be able to use the boolean difference and intersect to cut of parts of an object using a plane.
In this case, I need to cute a cubic building with poles at the location where the plane intersects the poles. See figure below

[image]

When I try to cut of the lower part of the poles (below the plane) using the difference function, it cuts of the upper part of the building. I would like to turn this around and cut the lower part of the poles instead of cutting the upper part of the building.
[image]

The intersect boolean cuts of everything that does not intersect, so only four small squares remain.
[image]
Does anyone have an idea whether it is possible to turn around which part is being cut of? Such that I can cut of the part of the building that is below the plane?

Comment: You need to invert the normal of the plane (in edit mode, SHIFT N, F9, click on "Inside")

Comment: You can use bisect instead, or you can change the plane normal as Gorgious suggested, or you can turn the plane around.